# How to write device driver programs in c language

Tags: c, linux, drivers

I want to code drivers in C in linux os, though I think its very tough. Can I get some hints as to how to start or books to follow? Drivers can be from my USB port to graphics card!!

I know as to where I can search for books, I would like to know as to what the basic knowledge I should start with. Do I need to have hardware knowledge and which specific books are good for novice like me

Comment: http://kernelnewbies.org/, http://lwn.net/Kernel/LDD3/

Comment: Before hacking the kernel, are you sure to be very fluent on the application-level Linux system interface (notably syscalls)? Do you know quite well http://advancedlinuxprogramming.com/ ? A general hint about hacking the kernel is : *don't hack the kernel if your goal can be achieved in userland* ....